# Implementing Loss function for Label Distribution Smoothing (LDS) in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, regression

Im trying to implement Label Distribution Smoothing (a technique for imbalanced regression) in Keras. But I'm running into an issue defining a custom weighted loss function for it. As the loss function needs to take in the current data row index to select the correct weight from a list of weights. My current loss function is:

```
def weighted_mse_loss(inputs, targets):
    global weights
    loss = (inputs - targets) ** 2
    if weights is not None:
        loss *= weights[index]
    loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(loss)
    return loss
```

The issue is that i can't find a way to get the data row index inside of a custom loss function in Keras. This technique was originally implemented using Pytorch [here](https://github.com/YyzHarry/imbalanced-regression) but I'm trying to port it to Keras. For reference here is my code for generating the weights array:

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d
from scipy.signal.windows import triang
from scipy.ndimage import convolve1d

def get_lds_kernel_window(kernel, ks, sigma):
    assert kernel in ['gaussian', 'triang', 'laplace']
    half_ks = (ks - 1) // 2
    if kernel == 'gaussian':
        base_kernel = [0.] * half_ks + [1.] + [0.] * half_ks
        kernel_window = gaussian_filter1d(base_kernel, sigma=sigma) / max(gaussian_filter1d(base_kernel, sigma=sigma))
    elif kernel == 'triang':
        kernel_window = triang(ks)
    else:
        laplace = lambda x: np.exp(-abs(x) / sigma) / (2. * sigma)
        kernel_window = list(map(laplace, np.arange(-half_ks, half_ks + 1))) / max(map(laplace, np.arange(-half_ks, half_ks + 1)))

    return kernel_window
def prepare_weights(data, reweight, max_target=51, lds=True, lds_kernel='gaussian', lds_ks=5, lds_sigma=2):
        assert reweight in {'none', 'inverse', 'sqrt_inv'}
        assert reweight != 'none' if lds else True, \
            "Set reweight to \'sqrt_inv\' (default) or \'inverse\' when using LDS"

        value_dict = {x: 0 for x in range(max_target)}
        # mbr
        labels = data['prcp'].tolist()
        # mbr
        for label in labels:
            value_dict[min(max_target - 1, int(label))] += 1
        if reweight == 'sqrt_inv':
            value_dict = {k: np.sqrt(v) for k, v in value_dict.items()}
        elif reweight == 'inverse':
            value_dict = {k: np.clip(v, 5, 1000) for k, v in value_dict.items()}  # clip weights for inverse re-weight
        num_per_label = [value_dict[min(max_target - 1, int(label))] for label in labels]
        if not len(num_per_label) or reweight == 'none':
            return None
        print(f"Using re-weighting: [{reweight.upper()}]")

        if lds:
            lds_kernel_window = get_lds_kernel_window(lds_kernel, lds_ks, lds_sigma)
            print(f'Using LDS: [{lds_kernel.upper()}] ({lds_ks}/{lds_sigma})')
            smoothed_value = convolve1d(
                np.asarray([v for _, v in value_dict.items()]), weights=lds_kernel_window, mode='constant')
            num_per_label = [smoothed_value[min(max_target - 1, int(label))] for label in labels]

        weights = [np.float32(1 / x) for x in num_per_label]
        scaling = len(weights) / np.sum(weights)
        weights = [scaling * x for x in weights]
        return weights

weights = tf.convert_to_tensor(prepare_weights(data,reweight='sqrt_inv',lds=True,lds_ks=9,lds_sigma=1),dtype="float32")
```

which has mostly been taken from the Pytorch implementation [here](https://github.com/YyzHarry/imbalanced-regression) and the paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09554).